# data type is numpy.ndarray but expected numpy.int64

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working on an assignment for my computational photography class using python. The method expects a `numpy.int64` and I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I've tried to `numpy.astype(int64)` but it gives me a global name not defined. I'm not sure how to do this. The error I get is `ValueError: Error - x_locs values have type <type 'numpy.ndarray'>. Expected value type is <type 'numpy.int64'>`.

```
def getYXLocations(image, intensity_value):
    """ This function gets the Y, X locations of an image at a certain intensity
    value.

    It's easy to describe how to do this visually. Imagine you have a grayscale
    image that is 4x4.
    my_image = [ [ 17, 200,  48,  10],
                 [ 98, 151,  41, 182],
                 [128, 190,  98, 209],
                 [249,  27, 129, 182]]

    Now assume I ask you to return getYXLocations(my_image, 98)

    You have to return the y and x locations of where 98 appears, so in this
    case, 98 appears at 1, 0 and at 2, 2, so your function should return
    y_locs = [1, 2] and x_locs = [0, 2].

    Hint: There is a numpy function that will essentially allow you to do this
    efficiently & succintly. May be worth looking into ;).

    The less efficient but equally valid way of doing this:
    1. Iterate through the rows (y) and columns (x) of the image.
    2. if image[y, x] == intensity_value, append y to y_locs and x to x_locs.
    3. return y_locs, x_locs.

    Args:
        image (numpy.ndarray): Input grayscale image.
        intensity_value (numpy.uint8): Assume a value from 0->255.

    Returns:
        y_locs (numpy.ndarray): Array containing integer values for the y
                                locations of input intensity. Type np.int64.
        x_locs (numpy.ndarray): Array containing integer values for the x
                                locations of input intensity. Type np.int64.
    """
    # WRITE YOUR CODE HERE.

    # dim of the image
    dim = image.shape

    # axis
    xax = dim[1]
    yax = dim[0]

    count = 0
    # loopings for count
    for x in range (0, xax):
        for y in range (0, yax):
            if image[x][y] == intensity_value:
                count = count + 1

    # creates x loc and y loc
    x_locs = np.empty([1, count], dtype=np.int64)
    y_locs = np.empty([1, count], dtype=np.int64)

    # loops for location
    place = 0
    for x in range (0, xax):
        for y in range (0, yax):
            if image[x][y] == intensity_value:
                x_locs[0][place] = x
                y_locs[0][place] = y
                place = place + 1

    print np.array_str(x_locs)
    print np.array_str(y_locs)

    # x_locs = x_locs.astype(int64)
    # y_locs = y_locs.astype(int64)

    return x_locs, y_locs
    # END OF FUNCTION
```

Here's the code to test the method if it helps.

```
def test_getYXLocations():

    test_input = np.array([[ 41, 200,  190,  41],
                           [ 98, 151,   41, 182],
                           [128, 190,   98, 209],
                           [ 41,  27,  129, 190]], dtype=np.uint8)
    test_intensities = [41, 190, 98, 182]

    test_answers = [[np.array([0, 0, 1, 3], dtype=np.int64),
                     np.array([0, 3, 2, 0], dtype=np.int64)], # 41
                    [np.array([0, 2, 3], dtype=np.int64),
                     np.array([2, 1, 3], dtype=np.int64)], # 190
                    [np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.int64),
                     np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.int64)], # 98
                    [np.array([1], dtype=np.int64),
                     np.array([3], dtype=np.int64)]] # 182


    for test_idx in xrange(len(test_intensities)):
        x_locs, y_locs = assignment8.getYXLocations(test_input,
                                                     test_intensities[test_idx])
        x_ans, y_ans = test_answers[test_idx]


        # Test type.
        if type(x_locs) != type(x_ans):
            raise ValueError(
                ("Error - x_locs has type {}." +
                 " Expected type is {}.").format(type(x_locs), type(x_ans)))
        if type(x_locs[0]) != type(x_ans[0]):
            raise ValueError(
                ("Error - x_locs values have type {}." +
                 " Expected value type is {}.").format(type(x_locs[0]),
                                                       type(x_ans[0])))

        # Test length (did you find the right amount of points).
        if len(x_locs) != len(x_ans):
            raise ValueError(
                ("Error - x_locs has len {}." +
                 " Expected len is {}.").format(len(x_locs), len(x_ans)))

        if len(x_locs) != len(y_locs):
            raise ValueError(
                ("The length of your outputs is not the same." +
                 "x_locs length: {} | y_locs length: {}.").format(len(x_locs),
                                                                  len(y_locs)))


        np.testing.assert_array_equal(y_locs, y_ans)
        np.testing.assert_array_equal(x_locs, x_ans)

    print "getYXLocations testing passed."
    return True
```

Comment: Even after correcting indention, that is too much code.  YOU need to narrow it down, giving us just the essentials.  And make it clear where the error is occuring.

Comment: The error message indicates that at some point the code expects an integer, or integer array Element.  Instead you are giving it an `array`.  Do you understand the distinction?

Comment: It probably isn't causing this error, but you should index the 2d array `image` with `[x,y]`, or `[0,0]` format, not `[0][0]`.

Comment: I think it is more useful, when debugging `numpy` code, to focus on getting the shapes right.  As the accepted answer notes, this was bascially an array dimension issue.  So I sprinkle my development code with `print arr.shape` like statements, or similar `assert` statements.  `dtype` isn't as diagnositic.  And `type` mainly helps distinguish lists from arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue comes from this check -

```
if type(x_locs[0]) != type(x_ans[0]):
        raise ValueError(
            ("Error - x_locs values have type {}." +
             " Expected value type is {}.").format(type(x_locs[0]),
                                                   type(x_ans[0])))
```

As you can see from your `test_answers`  , the type of `x_ans[0]` is `np.int64` , since x_ans is a single dimensional array.

But when you are creating `x_locs` in your other function , you are creating it as a 2D array , with the shape as (1,10) , hence when you access `x_locs[0]` , you get an array.

Some solutions that may work for you -

1. You are defining your `x_locs` and `y_locs` with having only 1 array inside it (which then has `count` amount of elements) , maybe you should define them as 1D arrays rather than 2D arrays (I can see that in your testing function, you are doing lots of test in the assumption that they are 1D array , but they are really not). To change them to 1D array , change the following line as -

   ```
   x_locs = np.empty([count], dtype=np.int64)
   y_locs = np.empty([count], dtype=np.int64)
   ```

   Please note, after this when you try to access the array , you should be using `x_locs[place]` , instead of `x_locs[0][place]` .
2. The other solution would be to correct your testing logic to handle `x_locs` and `y_locs` as 2D arrays, rather than 1D arrays.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please do remember to accept answers if they helped you (By clicking on the tick mark on the left of the answer so that is becomes green) , for all the questions you have asked as well. It would really help the community.